Select from series of columns without blanks and then where Google Sheets query
I have a Google Sheet with 18 columns that is mostly populated from a Google Form.
To simplify the form, I have used "Go to" and Form Ranger to simplify the options in the form. That results in columns EFG being "8th Grade Name, Class Leaving, and Going To" while columns HIJ are "7th Grade Name, Class Leaving, and Going To" an KLM are 6th Grade name, Class Leaving, and Going To."
I want to pull a report using a query formula but am not sure of the proper syntax or the proper question to ask.
Here is an example of what I have:



Timestamp
Email
Status
Grade
EEE
FFF
GGG
HHH
III
JJJ
KKK
LLL
MMM




Cell 1
Cell 2
In
data.
X
X
X








Cell 1
Cell 2
Out
data.



R
R
R





Cell 1
Cell 2
Out
data.
F
F
F








Cell 1
Cell 2
In
data.






G
G
G


Cell 1
Cell 2
Out
data.






V
V
V



On a different sheet, what I want to do is this:
=query(Table!$A:$M, "select A,@,@,@ where C='Out' order by A asc, @ asc)
The @,@,@ would be EFG or HIJ or KLM depending on which are not blank (null) and the last @ would be the name field used (either E, H, or K).
I want the result to look like this:



Timestamp
Email
Status
Grade
Name
Class
Location




Cell 1
Cell 2
Out
data.
R
R
R


Cell 1
Cell 2
Out
data.
F
F
F


Cell 1
Cell 2
Out
data.
V
V
V



How do I get the select within a select? I thought about a "select *" but I don't want all of the columns reported back out. My guess is that it includes a FROM but I'm not getting the syntax.


Here's one approach you may adapt/test out:
=query({A2:D,byrow(E2:M,lambda(Σ,torow(Σ,1)))},"Where Col3='Out'")



This helps eliminate the blanks (THANK YOU!). Is there a way to hide, or not show, columns B, C, and D in the result? I know I can "hide" the columns but I mean don't even pull it. I just want the results to pull A and then the non-blanks E-M like you did.

Use SELECT parameter as such: Select Col1, Col5, Col6, Col7 where.....

where would I put the select? If I just use "select Col1, Col5, Col6 where..." then how do I incorporate the lambda from above to eliminate the blanks? I tried using just the select but then it gives me all of the columns with or without data.

What @rockinfreakshow meant was to change "Where Col3='Out'" to "Select Col1, Col5, Col6, Col7 Where Col3='Out'". You don't have to edit the lambda part.

Works perfectly! Now I will work to learn exactly what it means so I can replicate when needed. I appreciate all the help!!
